# Odd issue with bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I have a page containing a bootstrap table, using the following code:

```
<table class="display table table-bordered table-striped w-100"
                                        data-click-to-select="true" data-unique-id="NoticeID"
                                        data-pagination="true" data-sortable="true" data-page-size="10"
                                        data-single-select="true" data-maintain-selected="true"
                                        data-id-field="NoticeID" id="notices" name="notices">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
              <th data-field="NoticeID" data-sortable="true">ID</th>
              <th data-field="Title" data-sortable="true">Title</th>
              <th data-field="TimesViewed" data-sortable="true">Views</th>
              <th data-field="IsActive" data-sortable="true">Active</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
</table>
```

In my page load script, I call the following function which uses an AJAX call to populate the table with data:

```
        function loadNotices() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '../handlers/getusernotices.ashx',
                data: null,
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#notices').bootstrapTable({
                        data: data.Notices
                    });
                    $('#notices').bootstrapTable('load', data.Notices);
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log(e.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
```

Everything works just fine, except for one little odd thing:  Looking at the screenshot below, you'll notice that the 'Loading, please wait...' message that the bootstrap table displays while data is being loaded never goes away, even after the data has been loaded:
[image: screenshot of result]

Am I missing something that I need to do once the table is loaded to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include bootstrap's table css in your html file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.20.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
```

If this doesn't work, try to include this js script after the rest of the scripts

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.20.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
```

Links from [here](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/getting-started/download/#unpkg)

Comment: You were right on this.  I had the JS file but somehow overlooked adding in the stylesheet.  Thank you for pointing out a dumb mistake on my part!

Answer (score 0):

In order to populate a table through AJAX, one option is to follow the example provided by the [documentation](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#options/table-ajax.html#view-source).

Analysing how the code works, you may notice that it calls the ajax function which receives `params` as argument. With that, you have to pass an object with the following structure:

```
{  
   rows: [
     { yourDataHere } , ...
   ]
}
```

And those columns have to correspond to the ones you described in the HTML through the `data-field` attribute. You can see this in action in the [running example](https://jsfiddle.net/p7qdxn52/).